# How to Iterate 'Values' of a Nested Dictionary from a Nested Dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

```
{'value1': [{"A":100, "B":2}], ‘value2’: [{"A":1, "B":2},{"A":2, "B":4},{"A":3, "B":2},{"A":4, "B":4}], ‘value3’: [{"A":10}]}
```

I want the value of key A to be printed as below may be by using forloop or something like that:

```
value1 = 100 , Value2 = 1,2,3,4, value3 = 10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the dict, look for the desired `key` and concatenate its value:

```
dd = {'value1': [{"A":100, "B":2}], 'value2': [{"A":1, "B":2},{"A":2, "B":4},{"A":3, "B":2},{"A":4, "B":4}], 'value3': [{"A":10}]}

res = []
for k,v in dd.items():
    s = ''
    for elem in v:
        for kk,vv in elem.items():
            if kk == 'A':
                s += str(elem[kk]) + ', '
    # print(k, s)
    res.append([k,s])

for e in res:
    print(" = ".join(e), end = "")
```

OUTPUT:

```
value1 = 100, value2 = 1, 2, 3, 4, value3 = 10,
```

Comment: Awesome....One more question that i missed, if the value1 or value2 also have the same nested in value2, how we can achieve it. {'value1': [{"A":100, "B":2},{"A":200, "B":2}]], ‘value2’: [{"A":1, "B":2},{"A":2, "B":4},{"A":3, "B":2},{"A":4, "B":4}], ‘value3’: [{"A":10},{"A":500, "B":2},{"A":600, "B":2}]]]}    Output as:value1 = 100,200  value2 = 1, 2, 3, 4, value3 = 10, 500,600

Answer (score 0):

you can create another dict with thise items:

```
a = {'value1': [{"A":100, "B":2}], 'value2': [{"A":1, "B":2},{"A":2, "B":4},{"A":3, 

"B":2},{"A":4, "B":4}], 'value3': [{"A":10}]}
list1 = []
b = {}
for k,v in a.items():
    for x in v:
        list1.append(x["A"])
    b[k] = list1
    list1 = []
print(b)
```

output:

```
{'value1': [100], 'value2': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'value3': [10]}
```

Comment: Thanks, One more question that i missed, if the value1 or value2 also have the same nested in value2, how we can achieve it. {'value1': [{"A":100, "B":2},{"A":200, "B":2}]], ‘value2’: [{"A":1, "B":2},{"A":2, "B":4},{"A":3, "B":2},{"A":4, "B":4}], ‘value3’: [{"A":10},{"A":500, "B":2},{"A":600, "B":2}]]]} Output as:value1 = 100,200 value2 = 1, 2, 3, 4, value3 = 10, 500,600